# ASP.NET WebAPI unable to post

Tags: f#

**I am unable to post data to a ASP.NET WebAPI server.**

I can get data from the WEBAPI server. However, I am unable to post.

The following code fails to post:

```
response = await client.PostAsync("api/Cars", content);
```

Error:

> StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1

**Client:**

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    // http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:48213/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // HTTP GET
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/Cars");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            // HTTP POST
            using (var content = new StringContent(@"some_value"))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                response = await client.PostAsync("api/Cars", content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Post was successful.");
                }
            }
        }
```

**WebAPI:**

```
namespace FSharpWebAPI.Controllers

open System.Web.Http
open FSharpWebAPI.Models

type CarsController() =
    inherit ApiController()

    let values = [| { Make = "Ford"; Model = "Mustang" }; { Make = "Nissan"; Model = "Titan" } |]

    member x.Get() = values

    member x.Post(data) = 
        ignore
```

What updates do I need to make just to make a simple post?

Comment: Your `x.Post` method is generic (takes parameter `data` of generic type) and returns a function. Doesn't look like a correct setup to me.

Comment: I just wanted to catch the breakpoint on it.

Comment: Web API won't hook it up unless it has correct shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Fyodor Soikin has pointed out, the `Post` method is generic (`'a -> 'b -> unit`), and ASP.NET Web API refuses to wire up such methods.

ASP.NET Web API uses *convention over configuration* in order to figure out how to route and handle incoming requests. If an HTTP POST arrives, it'll go hunting for a method (partially) named `Post`, and attempt to call it. While you could argue that if a generic method could handle the input, it'd be possible for Web API to still call it, it doesn't do that.

You'll need to add a type annotation - for example:

```
member x.Post(data : Car) = 
    ignore
```

That's probably still not going to be enough, because the type of that version of `Post` is `Car -> 'a -> unit`, so the return value is a generic function. I'd be surprised if Web API knows what to do with that.

The reason is that `ignore` is a *function*, and since `Post` doesn't *invoke* the function, the return value is the function itself.

If you want to ignore the input and return `unit`, you can simply do this:

```
member x.Post(data : Car) = ()
```

This version has the type `Car -> unit`, which I expect Web API will find acceptable.